# Non-insulated control of inverse parallel SCRs

Tags: solid-state-relay, triac, scr

I'm converting an inverse parallel (a.k.a. anti-parallel, back-to-back) SCR load switch from insulated control to non-insulated control.  Here is the original circuit using an optotriac to turn on the SCRs:

[image: Insulated circuit]

From OnSemi's [Thyristor Theory and Design Considerations](https://edisciplinas.usp.br/pluginfile.php/2587503/mod_resource/content/2/Onsemi_Thyristor_Theory_and_Design_Considerations_Handbook_HBD855-D.pdf) pp. 117-118, I want to replace the optotriac with a small TRIAC with non-insulated control:

[image: OnSemi's philosophy]

My first stab at this conversion was to copy a small(ish) TRIAC circuit from elsewhere in the schematic:

[image: Non-insulated circuit]

A non-insulated (hot-side) microcontroller that is referenced to L1_SRC and -3V3_HOT will toggle Q34-A.

Am I missing anything?  Simulations in LTspice won't converge, and my lab access has been constricted since spring.  I know that I'll probably have to reconsider the gate resistances of R9, R123, and R311; but the rest just seemed too easy.

Comment: Is there a compelling reason why back-to-back SCRs are used instead of a triac? Is there a reason why you want non-insulated control?

Comment: @Andyaka the load I'm controlling is at least 1500 W @ 240 V, and dumping optotriacs is preferred for cost and reliability.  Requirements are still in flux, so the load may increase and phase versus cycle control still hasn't been decided.  TRIACs that can switch that much current are tough to come by for under several dollars, and it's a bit of a design risk right now to switch.

Comment: @Andyaka Triacs do not have perfectly symmetrical behaviour. Triacs are also manufactured as a poor man's back-to-back SCR and are apparently not manufactured to be quite as rugged as a result and also have less selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is perfectly fine and works very nicely.
[image: tirisztorok]

[image]

There are still large enough reserves for the values ​​of resistors R9, R123 and R311.

Comment: Thanks for that!  Which SPICE program are you using?

Comment: I just used Tina (v 9.3) now, but I have LTSpice, Tina-TI, and PSpice for TI 2020. Depending on what I want to model, I always need another one.